# Uniform convergence of $\sum_{n = 1}^\infty {\arctan{\frac{2x}{x^2+n^2}}}$ on $\mathbb R$

Tags: functions, uniform-convergence

> Check if $\sum_\limits{n = 1}^\infty{\arctan{\dfrac{2x}{x^2+n^2}}}$ is uniformly convergent series of function on $\mathbb{R}$.

"Uniform convergence" really messes up my mind.

Since $\dfrac{2x}{x^2+n^2} \approx \arctan{\dfrac{2x}{x^2+n^2}}$ when $n\to\infty$, could I use the uniform convergence of $\sum_\limits{n = 1}^\infty{\dfrac{2x}{x^2+n^2}}$ to check the uniform convergence of $\sum_\limits{n = 1}^\infty{\arctan{\dfrac{2x}{x^2+n^2}}}$?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: That might provide some intuition, but it isn't a rigorous proof. Let's start from the start: do you know the definition of a sequence of functions *converging uniformly*? Can you articulate how that differs from a sequence of functions just converging?

Comment: To **disprove** uniform convergence on $\mathbb R$, note that, considering $$f_n(x)=\arctan\left(\frac{2x}{x^2+n^2}\right)$$ one has $$\sum_{k=n+1}^{2n}f_k(n)\geqslant nf_{2n}(n)=n\arctan\left(\frac2{5n}\right)\geqslant\frac25$$ which does not converge to $0$.

Comment: @Did I think $\arctan{x} < x$ for $x>0$, then $n\arctan\left(\frac2{5n}\right)\leqslant\frac25$

Comment: @dienhosp3 Indeed, silly me. But the proof works all right nevertheless, replacing the last step by $$n\arctan\left(\frac2{5n}\right)\geqslant\arctan\left(\frac2{5}\right)$$ ...And anyway the basic idea is simply that $$\liminf_{n\to\infty} \left(n\arctan\left(\frac2{5n}\right)\right)>0$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your heuristics may give some idea, but any such heuristics should be justified in order to yield a valid proof.

Let me demonstrate a possible way. It follows from AM-GM inequality that

$$ \left|\frac{2x}{x^2 + n^2}\right| \leq \frac{1}{n} $$

uniformly in $x \in \Bbb{R}$. Together with the inequality $\frac{1}{2}|x| \leq |\arctan x| \leq |x|$ which holds for $|x| \leq 1$, we find that

$$ \frac{1}{2} \left\| \sum_{n=M}^{N} \frac{2x}{x^2 + n^2} \right\|_{\sup}
\leq \left\| \sum_{n=M}^{N} \arctan\left( \frac{2x}{x^2 + n^2} \right) \right\|_{\sup}
\leq \left\| \sum_{n=M}^{N} \frac{2x}{x^2 + n^2} \right\|_{\sup}. $$

That is, $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \arctan( \frac{2x}{x^2 + n^2} )$ is uniformly Cauchy if and only if $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{2x}{x^2 + n^2}$ is uniformly Cauchy. This is enough to conclude that we can investigate the uniform convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{2x}{x^2 + n^2}$ .

---

Now let us prove that the series does not converge uniformly. **@Did** already provided a short and elegant solution for this, but let me articulate a little bit by showing that, loosely speaking, 'positive mass' concentrates near the infinity.

Let $S(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{2x}{x^2 + n^2}$ and we write $S(x)$ as

$$ S(x) = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{2}{1 + (\frac{n}{x})^2} \frac{1}{x}. $$

We can recognize $S(x)$ as a Riemann sum of the function $f(t) = \frac{2}{1+t^2}$. To prove that this is indeed true, let $x > 0$ and notice that

$$ \int_{\frac{n}{x}}^{\frac{n+1}{x}} \frac{2}{1+t^2} \, dt
\leq \frac{2}{1 + (\frac{n}{x})^2} \frac{1}{x}
\leq \int_{\frac{n-1}{x}}^{\frac{n}{x}} \frac{2}{1+t^2} \, dt $$

for all $n \geq 1$. Summing over $n$ and taking limit as $x \to \infty$, this proves that

$$ \lim_{x\to\infty} S(x) = \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{2}{1+t^2} \, dt = \pi. $$

This is enough to conclude that $S(x)$ does not converge uniformly, since any partial sum $S_N(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{N} \frac{2x}{x^2 + n^2}$ satisfies

$$ \lim_{x\to\infty} S_N(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{N} \lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{2x}{x^2 + n^2} = 0 $$

and hence there is no way we have $\| S_N - S \|_{\sup} \to 0$ as $N \to \infty$.